# Downloading Sharepoint using Python

Tags: python, sharepoint

I am required to download a file from Sharepoint and modify it and reupload it, all these in Python. At first I thought it was a permission related issue, but it wasn't as I tried my code on other Public Sharepoint link.

**Attempt #1**

*Code:*

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File

url = 'Sharepoint Link'
username = 'username'
password = 'password'

ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password)  
ctx = ClientContext(url, ctx_auth)
response = File.open_binary(ctx, "/Shared Documents/Data.xlsx")
with open("./Data.xlsx", "wb") as local_file:
local_file.write(response.content)
```

*Expectation:*

- For the file to download into local drive.

*Result:*

- Said file was downloaded, however it comes along with this error "Excel file cannot be open because the file format or file extension is not valid."

*Solution:*

- Tried allowing access to all users
- Tried closing all opening Excel files

**Attempt #2**

*Code:*

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import io

url = 'Sharepoint Link'
username = 'username'
password = 'password'

response = requests.get(url, auth=(username, password))
bytes_file_obj = io.BytesIO(response.content)
df = pd.read_excel(bytes_file_obj, sheet_name=sheet_name, engine='openpyxl')
print("Excel file downloaded")
```

*Expectation:*

- For the file to download into local drive.

*Result:*

- Said file was downloaded, however it comes along with this error "Excel file cannot be open because the file format or file extension is not valid."

*Solution:*

- Tried allowing access to all users
- Tried closing all opening Excel files
- Tried specifying the engines

**Attempt #3**

*Code:*

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import openpyxl
import io
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File

url = 'Sharepoint Link'
username = 'username'
password = 'password'
sheet_name = 'table'

ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password):
ctx = ClientContext(url, ctx_auth)
web = ctx.web
ctx.load(web)
ctx.execute_query()
print("Authentication successful")
response = File.open_binary(ctx, url)
bytes_file_obj = io.BytesIO()
bytes_file_obj.write(response.content)
bytes_file_obj.seek(0)  
df = pd.read_excel(bytes_file_obj, sheet_name=sheet_name)
print("Excel file loaded successfully")
```

*Expectation:*

- For the file to download into local drive.

*Result:*

- Said file was downloaded, however it comes along with this error "Excel file cannot be open because the file format or file extension is not valid."

*Solution:*

- Tried allowing access to all users
- Tried closing all opening Excel files
- Tried specifying the engines

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error.  Also, are you certain the original file isn't corrupted?  One option you can do is to store it directly to a file and open that file with Excel.

Comment: Hi, yes, I was able to download the original file and double checked that it's not corrupted. As for the code, the code was able to run hence there is no error but when opening the file, it will always say that the file is corrupted.